# Logstash Grok Pattern for Cisco swithc logs

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I having a syslog message from Cisco switch as below

```
<189>11762: SW01: ]: Oct 19 15:46:15.776 GMT: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5, changed state to up
```

I am trying to remove ] after SW01 and was successful using the below pattern:

```
<%{NUMBER:message_type_id}>%{NUMBER:internal_id}:%{SPACE}%{SYSLOGHOST:origin_hostname}:%{SPACE}\]:%{SPACE}%{CISCOTIMESTAMP:cisco_timestamp}
```

This Pattern Produce the following output:

```
{
"internal_id": "11762",
"cisco_timestamp": "Oct 19 15:46:15.776",
"message_type_id": "189",
"origin_hostname": "SW01"
}
```

But when i try to add on further pattern after timestamp as following:

```
\%%{WORD:facility}-%{INT:severity}-%{WORD:mnemonic}: %{GREEDYDATA:msg}
```

GrokDebugger:

```
Provided Grok patterns do not match data in the input
```

How can i match a pattern to the above syslog message?

Any help is highly appreciated

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
<%{NUMBER:message_type_id}>%{NUMBER:internal_id}:%{SPACE}%{SYSLOGHOST:origin_hostname}:%{SPACE}\]:%{SPACE}%{CISCOTIMESTAMP:cisco_timestamp}%{SPACE}%{DATA:gmt}:%{SPACE}%{PROG}%{WORD:facility}-%{INT:severity}-%{WORD:mnemonic}:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:msg}
```